# Having two different GIT repo's in one directory for the same project

Tags: git, github, repository, gitlab

I wanted to know if it is possible to have 2 different GIT repositories in one root folder for the same project, and if I can add/commit/push to both of them without anything getting messed up.

**Example of what I want to achieve:**

I have a Django project and I have it in 2 different repositories. One being on https://github.com that I use for automatic deployment on Heroku, and the second repository on https://gitlab.com where I have all my legit commits/Messages/Tickets/Issues/CI/etc.

Is it possible to somehow get both repos to be in 1 directory where my Django project is and then for me to just do

`git add .`

`git commit -m "message"`

`git push origin "whatever"`

and get my commits pushed to both repos?

At the moment I have the project in 2 different directories where the gitlab one is my main project and then I copy paste the files into the github one and push there so I can deploy the changes on Heroku.

P.S I would prefer to have my automatic deploys from the github repo without setting up any deployments from gitlab.

Thanks, please comment if you are downvoting this post, so I can improve quality. This is my 1st question!

Thank you!

**EDIT 09-07-2017:**

I have found a way to easily deploy my Django Project to Heroku without the need of a github repo. For any future people that might come across this question, here is how I achieved deploying my Django Project to Heroku via a https://gitlab.com repo in the most hacky/fast way without much of a setup:

1. Locate your Heroku-API key [Heroku](https://dashboard.heroku.com/account), if the link no longer works just go to your Heroku Account settings and in there you will find your Heroku API key
2. After you have setup your Procfile, wsgi.py, etc (all the Deployment setup), push all the changes to your master branch on gitlab.
3. Finally you want to do the following commands in order to deploy to Heroku:

   `git remote add heroku https://"API-key"@git.heroku.com/"app_name".git`

   (without the quotes example: `https://xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx@git.heroku.com/django_app.git`)

   then you fire up this:

   `git push -f heroku master`

   This might ask you to authenticate, so just use your heroku credentials.

Hope this was of help to you!

Comment: You can use multiple remotes, you're not restricted to just `origin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFIR Gitlab.com has option to push mirror repository to other git servers. Go to `Project Settings -> Repository -> Push to a remote repository`

> Set up the remote repository that you want to update with the content of the current repository every time someone pushes to it. Read more
>   Remote mirror repository
>
> Automatically update the remote mirror's branches, tags, and commits from this repository every time someone pushes to it.

With that you can have only one remote origin and Gitlab will push all your changes to Github. I wish that feature could be added to self-hosted Gitlab-CE.

Comment: So this feature is not available on the free edition of gitlab?

Comment: Gitlab.com uses EE version and I was talking about self-hosted CE version.

Comment: Ok I just entered the project settings and found it. I will update my question and mark this as Accepted Answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not much of a fan of this idea - having two repositories and then copy-paste from one to another. One approach you can use is using GitFlow. You'll only need one repository (whichever you choose). You will work with branches and you will have one branch for production, that will be used for deployment. You can read more about it (about other workflows as well) [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows#gitflow-workflow) or you can search it by yourself.

Good luck!